# Install local app on Windows Tablet

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, xap

I have Acer ICONIA Tab with windows 8.1 pro. I have a test XAP file which I want to install on it. but I can't find any option in the App store to install local apps? Is it possible to install app locally? What I have tried is

- Copy the .XAP file to an external SD card, and try to install from App Store, but I can't see any option to install local app.

Any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

XAP files are Windows Phone Apps which can't be installed on a normal Windows 8.1

Comment: Windows Store Apps for Windows are AppX files. The way to deploy them is called Sideloading: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613831.aspx